# Telegram bot. Обработка сообщений, которые ввожу руками

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

Подскажите, каким способом нужно реализовать обработку сообщений? Например:
1. пишу "/test"
2. бот отвечает "Сколько?"
3. Я пишу, например "400"
4. Бот отвечает "Да"
5. пишу "/test2"
6. бот отвечает "Сколько?"
7. Я пишу, например "400"
8. Бот отвечает "Нет"
В общем, в зависимости от того какая была первоначальная команда(/test или /test2) бот мой ответ "400" обработает по разному.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал, для простоты реализации, использовать разные вопросы, чтобы их можно было передавать в `ForceReply`. То есть, например, не "Сколько?", а "Сколько для test?". Тогда можно будет понять, на какой именно вопрос отвечает пользователь. Если такой вариант не годится, то, наверное, придётся хранить состояния.

Comment: Нужно использовать [`CallBackQuery`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery)